# Problem when opening file AND possibly file i/o to string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to write a program which will copy a file into a string (so far so good on that) which will contain DNA bases. The bases are then converted into proteins, first finding the first ATG sequence, then reading in sequences of 3 and convertind them, writing them to another file.

As of now, the program crashes before entering the first for loop.. And I don't know what's causing the problem.

```
int proteina(char DNA_origem[], char proteina_destino[]){
char aminocidosING [64][14]={"Isoleucine","Isoleucine","Isoleucine","Leucine","Leucine","Leucine","Leucine","Leucine","Leucine","Valine","Valine","Valine","Valine","Phenylalanine","Phenylalanine","Methionine","Cysteine","Cysteine","Alanine","Alanine","Alanine","Alanine","Glycine","Glycine","Glycine","Glycine","Proline","Proline","Proline","Proline","Threonine","Threonine","Threonine","Threonine","Serine","Serine","Serine","Serine","Serine","Serine","Tyrosine","Tyrosine","Tryptophan","Glutamine","Glutamine","Asparagine","Asparagine","Histidine","Histidine","Glutamic acid","Glutamic acid","Aspartic acid","Aspartic acid","Lysine","Lysine","Arginine","Arginine","Arginine","Arginine","Arginine","Arginine","Stop codons","Stop codons","Stop codons"};
char aminocidosPT [64][18]={"Isoleucina","Isoleucina","Isoleucina","Leucina","Leucina","Leucina","Leucina","Leucina","Leucina","Valina","Valina","Valina","Valina","Fenilalanina","Fenilalanina","Metionina","Cisteína","Cisteína","Alanina","Alanina","Alanina","Alanina","Glicina","Glicina","Glicina","Glicina","Prolina","Prolina","Prolina","Prolina","Treonina","Treonina","Treonina","Treonina","Serina","Serina","Serina","Serina","Serina","Serina","Tirosina","Tirosina","Triptofano","Glutamina*","Glutamina","Asparagina","Asparagina","Histidina","Histidina","Ácido glutâmico","Ácido glutâmico","Ácido aspártico","Ácido aspártico","Lisina","Lisina","Arginina","Arginina","Arginina","Arginina","Arginina","Arginina","Códons Stop","Códons Stop","Códons Stop"};
char codoes[64][3]={"ATT","ATC","ATA","CTT","CTC","CTA","CTG","TTA","TTG","GTT","GTC","GTA","GTG","TTT","TTC","ATG","TGT","TGC","GCT","GCC","GCA","GCG","GGT","GGC","GGA","GGG","CCT","CCC","CCA","CCG","ACT","ACC","ACA","ACG","TCT","TCC","TCA","TCG","AGT","AGC","TAT","TAC","TGG","CAA","CAG","AAT","AAC","CAT","CAC","GAA","GAG","GAT","GAC","AAA","AAG","CGT","CGC","CGA","CGG","AGA","AGG","TAA","TAG","TGA"};
char proteinas[64][1] = {"I","I","I","L","L","L","L","L","L","V","V","V","V","F","F","M","C","C","A","A","A","A","G","G","G","G","P","P","P","P","T","T","T","T","S","S","S","S","S","S","Y","Y","W","Q","Q","N","N","H","H","E","E","D","D","K","K","R","R","R","R","R","R",".",".","."};

/* a esta altura suponho que tenhas definido na main as strings dos aminoácidos*/


char **string1; 
FILE * ficheiro;
FILE * ficheiro_close;
int f_cmp; 
int k, i, start=0; /* variavel de comprimento */
char proteina_origem;

ficheiro = fopen(DNA_origem,"r"); /* DNA origem e a variavel onde ta guardada o nome do ficheiro do utilizador */
ficheiro_close = fopen(proteina_destino,"w+");

fscanf(ficheiro,"%c",string1); /* isto lê os conteudos da stream para a string, copiando pra lá o ficheiro. */

for(i=1;i<=f_cmp;i++) {

   if (strncmp(string1[i],codoes[15],3)==0) {
      fputs(proteinas[15],ficheiro_close);

      for(k=i+2;k<=f_cmp;k+3) {

         if ((strncmp(string1[k],codoes[k],3))==0) {
            fputs(proteinas[k],ficheiro_close);

            if (k==61&&k==62&&k==63) {
                return(0);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Also, the compiler gives a warning if I don't use ** in char defining. Could you shed some light please? This should be just a simple project but I'm stuck in this last function..

Don't mind the var names and comments, it's in portuguese.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Make sure `ficheiro` is a valid file pointer before you are using it (by checking `if(ficheiro)`

Comment: I had a printf before, to test, printing out the variable, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Also there's a bit of code missing , but it still doesn't work, just in case, before the for loop, `f_cmp=strlen(*string1);`

Comment: Okay, so that's probably not it then, but you should still check your file pointers anyway :)

Comment: String1 bothers me on a number of fronts, as first it's used like a character in fscanf.  Then you try to use it like a string by dereferencing it, but it's not a string... And you skip the 0th member (arrays go from 0 to size-1 in C), so you will likely overstep the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pointers, then after declaration you have to initialize the pointer with suitable valid memory. After initialization, pointer is only pointing to an address, either to some other variable's address or the memory you create for this pointer (e.g. using malloc() or new operator).
Better use a char array, if it does not harm your coding approach to accomplish you task at hand.

However if you declare string1 as

```
char** string1
```

use fscanf like this:

```
fscanf(ficheiro,"%c", *string1);
```

Comment: When a pointer is only declared, It is not at all pointing to an address.

Comment: @DaRk_f0x: Try using cin>> or getline() instead of fscanf, or use fstream objects to read from files as this is more convenient. But this is my suggestion, it is up to you to decide which one suits better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one problem is with your [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) call.  You are attempting to scan a value and store it in the string1 variable, but there is no memory allocated for string1.  As you have it now, string1 is just a pointer to a pointer to a char, so there is no place to store the actual string value.  You could either allocate it on the stack, or allocate it on the heap.  Try something like this:

```
char string1[80]; // Or use whatever size makes sense here

...

fscanf(ficheiro, "%c", string1);
```

Also, you might be doing this already, but you should [`fclose`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fclose/) your FILEs when you're done with them.

Comment: I had the program running with `char string1[10]` and it still didn't work, maybe because the file is supposedly unknown size? In string it would be 1200+ chars long.

Comment: Also the file never has a fixed size, because i've worked with char string[] before successfully, but seems the unknown size might be the problem..

Comment: @DaRk_f0x: Don't be shy about making the string ample - e.g. 16384, 65536 - it's on the stack and will be reclaimed when the function exits.  BUT: %c only reads one character - you probably want "%s" or "%[xyz]" - read your `scanf` manpage.  Better still, use C++'s mechanisms: `if (std::ifstream ficheiro(DNA_origem)) { std::string string1; if (std::getline(ficheiro, string1)) { ... } }`.  `std::string` can grow to any size.  Does your file really have only one line?

Comment: @OP: you want to read line by line using fscanf ? That is a bad idea unless you want tokenized read from file. for reading lines use fgets function. And if you need to know the size of the file beforehand use stat function to get all the attributes/parameters associated with the file..which includes file size in bytes.

Comment: This is a project for my girlfriend's class and the teacher is against them using more advanced stuff.. I was supposed to design the loop only using fputc and fgetc and the like, not even fcnaf to work with a string would normally be allowed if I listened to all that the guy says.. But I can't get it to work with such basic commands since I have to seek in blocks of 3 =\

Comment: ohhk...but you can use fgets if you can use fgetc :P

Comment: And no, I don't want to read line by line, normally DNA sequences have newline characters every n bases so I would really love for a way to copy the whole file to the string and use it as such..

Comment: Well yeah but fgets reads until a newline character, which my file has, lots.

Comment: hmmm...if you really want to copy whole file to a string..then either define a big ahar array that can hold the file and then go on appending the output of fgets to the char array or dynamically allocate memory to hold charactersfor each fgets and then later concatenate it.

Comment: As I said, I would gladly do that but I can't use more complex code than fgetc and fputc, even fscanf is already pushing it.. But thanks :)

Comment: Still I'm sure I have a mistake somewhere. I'll try defining a bigger array that I know can contain the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong :

```
fscanf(ficheiro,"%c",string1);
```

I see string1 only declare but not initialized.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean :S

Comment: Just what others were saying. char ** string1 needs to be pointed to some memory..either on stack or on heap. Since you have not done either..fscanf will fail.